# Fixing MBP battery which has been sitting

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I have a new battery that has only 3 or 4 cycles on it, that I got as a replacement a year ago. The battery and the machine it's in, a late 2008 MBP, has been sitting for the last year unused. I tried to boot it up today and it appears the battery is toast. OS X reports it as "Replace Now". I tried to charge it for a few hours but the machine shut off as soon as I unplugged it. Is there a way I resurrect this battery?

Comment: Try an SMC reset, just to be sure. http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html:

> If you don’t plan on using your notebook for more than six months, Apple recommends that you store the battery with a 50% charge. **If you store a battery when it’s fully discharged, it could fall into a deep discharge state, which renders it incapable of holding any charge.** Conversely, if you store it fully charged for an extended period of time, the battery may experience some loss of battery capacity, meaning it will have a shorter life.

So you are most probably out of luck.

Comment: This same problem befell a customer of a certain electric car manufacturer that shall remain nameless. They have a disclaimer stating that the battery should never fall below a certain percentage.